# Magento - Adding Files to Local/Mage has no Effect

Tags: magento

I would like to make changes to some Magento core files.  To make sure the changes are future proof I copy the file from code/core/Mage to code/local/Mage.

I keep the file structures and file names consistent.  The problem is when I do this the changes have no effect (I've refreshed the cache)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  If I edit the core files directly the changes take place.

Comment: the local folder is for custom modules. For core changes you need to edit them directly in code/core/Mage.

Comment: That is not the recommended way.

Comment: What Rito says is not true, you can edit in local.

Comment: well i tested it myself on magento 1.4 a hour ago, the way a1anm tried doesnt work. As Janus wrote a new module is a nice solution.

Comment: From my experience, using local/Mage is ok for Block (and Model?).
As soon as you need to overwrite another part of the MVC, a custom module is mandatory.

Comment: Could you add the specific files you're trying to change, and the exact paths of where you're putting them?  There a lot if confusion in the community around these issues, as there's multiple ways to customize magento

Comment: The file I was trying to edit was:
app > code > core > Mage > Customer > etc > config.xml

I tried copying it to: 
app > code > local > Mage > Customer > etc > config.xml

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new local module and define rewrites in the config.xml file:

Create `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule` directory. Add subfolders `etc` and `model`.

Now create `etc/config.xml` file containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>

    <global>
         <models> <!-- type of class to rewrite -->
            <catalog> <!-- base module to rewrite -->
                <rewrite>
                    <product>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Implement `model/Product.php` with your changes. Easiest way is to inherit from the base class and rewrite the metho.

Also remember to activate your module in app/etc/modules.

Answer (score 0):

The above poster is correct in that the preferred way to edit core functionality is to use rewrites. In some cases, though, this isn't possible, in which case you should be able to place core files into the `/app/code/local/Mage` directory to get them to work. Block and Model files should work immediately in this way, as should controllers if I remember correctly. Other files (such as config files) may not be automatic.

Could you post the details of a particular file that doesn't respond as you expect? It's easier to debug particulars than generalities. Also, make sure that you have shut off any opcode cache that you have installed on the server in addition to flushing the normal cache.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: With config files you just place the overwrites verbatim in your modules config.xml or in local.xml.

Comment: You can't overwrite classes that are not instantiated the Mage class. So, stuff like Mage_Model_Catalog_Product_Abstract can't be done this way. Basically, it doesn't work with inheritance since the "normal" class name is used here.

Comment: The file I was trying to edit was:
app > code > core > Mage > Customer > etc > config.xml

I tried copying it to: 
app > code > local > Mage > Customer > etc > config.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can easily overwrite xml settings using `local.xml`. So, if you want to overwrite/add to `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml` you just add it to `app/etc/local.xml`.